# Each loop not returning the correct amount for each entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using ruby on rails with stripe which is a payment platform. The issue is on the pages to sell items there are multiple items each with a different amount to pay. Right now what is happening is that the loop gets the amount for the very last item and gives that amount to every item on the page rather then each having its own unique amount.

```
  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
          data-description="Purchase Book"
          new1=<%=
      listing_amount = @listing.amount
      @offers = @listing.offers
      @offers.each do |offer|
      offer_interest = offer.interest
      offer_month = offer.months
      @amount = (listing_amount * offer_interest * offer_month / 12).to_i
      end%>


          data-amount="<%=@amount %>"
```

The data-amount variable at the end is where it is getting the value for each item while the code above that is how I am trying to evaluate the @amount for each item. Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First this is that you should always put such code in helpers not views. Value of @amount is changing everytime it enter in the loop and final amount will be amount calculated in the last. So the code is actually returning

```
offer = @offers.last
offer_interest = offer.interest
offer_month = offer.months
@amount = (listing_amount * offer_interest * offer_month / 12).to_i
```

I am not sure what do you want to do as whole code is not visible.

Question1: If you have multiple items then why you initializing one variable as integer/float

Question2: I do not see where you showing item detail? Are you using loop multiple time?

question3: Why new1 variable is initialized with a loop that too a script tag?